# How can you compare words within a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compare

Basically I want to check a string array to see if any of the words match "and".

1. Is this possible?
2. Can you push me in the right direction?

Thanks

I should make it clear that the words are char put together best way to explain is an example

abc defg hijk and lmnop <-- each character is in its own element

Comment: To continue this sequence of numbers: thirdly, what have you tried?

Comment: basically if (stringName == "and") {output to console};

Comment: @eboix why use `strcmp` when `std::string` already has the `compare` function?

Comment: you have to see if the word you find is a really the word "and", and not "land" or other for example :)), so you have to care about separators (space, ',', '.', ...). unless there is an stl function that do that.

Comment: @eharvest: The question gave me the impression the words are already split and stored in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use `std::string` and not null-terminated `char*` strings (maybe you already are -- hard to be sure). And use a standard container rather than an array. Then use [`std::find`](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/find.html) (which would work on an array too, but containers are better).

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array and use [`int string::compare ( const string& str ) const;`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) to check for matches.

Break from the loop on first match.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you'd like to take care of lower\upper casing and the word appearing in the beginning\end of the string.

```
std::string data;
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
data.append(' ');
if (data.find("and ") != std::string::npos) ......
```